# Using apex:image path as javascript variable

Tags: apex, javascript, jquery

I am facing an issue with javascipt . Unable to save the path of image from static resource .

```
var backImage = '<apex:image value="{!URLFOR($Resource.testing, '/test/images/Back.png')}"/>';
```

I have tried replacing inside single quote with `&apos;.` But its not working any idea.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can we see a bit more code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static resources are not parsed for merge fields. You have to calculate the value within Visualforce itself and assign the value to a variable for your script to refer to.

---

```
<!-- in Visualforce -->
<script>
  var someUrl = "{!JSENCODE(URLFOR($Resource, 'path/to/file.ext'))}";
</script>
```

---

```
// In static resource
(function() {
  var someUrl = window.someUrl;
  // Do stuff with someUrl;
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I've rendered the entire js expression from Apex:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  {!imgTag}
</script>
```

and in the controller

```
public string imgTag {get {
  return 'var backImage = ' + URLFOR($Resource.testing, '/test/images/Back.png') + '/>';
  }; }
```

Comment: Isn't there any way to make it in javascript itself.

Comment: Sure, but it's a bit dangerous. You can always eval() the output.

Comment: Can you given an example . That would be a great help.

Comment: use SFDC Foxes answer